# How to prove finite abelian group is direct sum of cyclic groups by using matrices over Euclidean domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, modules, abelian-groups

Exercise from *Algebra, Chapter $0$* by Aluffi:

Prove

> [image]

using this proposition:

> [image]

---

I'm totally lost as to how to begin. How would we relate finite abelian groups to this theorem dealing with matrices over a Euclidean Domain?

My only guess to start would be to let $R=\mathbb Z$ (since abelian groups are $\mathbb Z$-modules). I know also that $M_{m,n}(\mathbb Z) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb Z-\mathrm{Mod}}(\mathbb Z^n, \mathbb Z^m)$ (which is itself a $\mathbb Z$-module).

**Am I on the right track? Any ideas on how to go about this?**

Comment: I think the trick here is that you can present any finite abelian group (or any finitely generates abelian group for that matter) as $\Bbb Z^n$ subject to certain columns being set equal to zero. Put these columns together to form the matrix $P$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $G$ is a finitely generated abelian group, generated by $m$ elements. Then it's a quotient of $\Bbb Z^m$, since $\Bbb Z^m$ is the free abelian group on $m$ generators. Next, the kernel of $\Bbb Z^m\to G$ is again a free abelian group, since every submodule of a free module over a PID is again free. So we can write a presentation for our group as $\Bbb Z^n\to \Bbb Z^m\to G$, and now we get to apply the theorem to the matrix which represents the first map.

Knowing this, see if you can figure out how to apply it for our situation of finite $G$. I'll leave the full answer in the following spoiler:

> In our case, as $G$ is finite, every generator has finite order, and thus $m=n$. So the matrix in question is square, and it cannot have any zeros on the diagonal - if it did, there would be an element of infinite order. So we have that $G\cong \Bbb Z/d_1\times \cdots \times \Bbb Z/d_n$. From here, you can use the standard fact that $\Bbb Z/a\cong \Bbb Z/b\times\Bbb Z/c$ if $a=bc$ and $(b,c)=1$ to verify the $p$-group assertion.

Comment: Is $\mathbb Z^n = \ker (\mathbb Z^m \to G)$?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Is there an easy way to see that every submodule of $\mathbb Z^m$ is free? I was looking for the general result you mentioned over $\mathrm{PID}$s, and found that it is proven a few sections later in the text (page $350$).

Comment: The algorithm used to prove Proposition 2.11 should be able to solve this problem in the finitely generated case. I suspect if you read the proof a few sections later you may not need any other material than what's needed for 2.11 depending on the way the book treats it.

Comment: Ok I had to look at the spoiler and have more questions. If $m=n$, then $\mathbb Z^m=\mathbb Z^n = \ker(\mathbb Z^m \to G)$ which implies $\mathbb Z^m \to G$ is the zero map. How can this be?

Comment: Also, I am not sure how you are concluding $G\cong \Bbb Z/d_1\times \cdots \times \Bbb Z/d_n$. How are we going from the matrix to $G$?

Comment: What? That's not even true in the case when $n=m=1$! Consider $\Bbb Z\stackrel{\cdot 2}{\to} \Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/2$. There are many proper copies of $\Bbb Z^m$ inside $\Bbb Z^m$. The connection between the matrix and $G$ is that the matrix picks out the relations that one enforces on the generators of $G$. Think about the example of $\Bbb Z/2$ again - the matrix here is just $(2)$, and sure enough $2$ times the generator of $\Bbb Z/2$ is zero.

Comment: Ah ok, I see that the map is necessarily trivial. But I still don't understand how we go from matrices to saying the group is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/d_1\times \cdots \times \Bbb Z/d_n$. I see the connection with the matrices but how are to say $G\cong \Bbb Z/d_1\times \cdots \times \Bbb Z/d_n$? How is it that we are concluding $G\cong \Bbb Z/d_1\times \cdots \times \Bbb Z/d_n$?

Comment: How do we go from the matrix of the $\mathbb Z$-module hom $Z^n \to Z^m$ is square with diagonal entries $d_1, d_2, \dots, d_r$ implies $G \cong \Bbb Z/d_1\times \cdots \times \Bbb Z/d_n$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97018/discussion-between-kreiser-and-al-jebr).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach, which fleshes out the idea I put forward in my comment. We'll think of $G$ as a $\Bbb Z$-module.  That is: $G$ denotes the group, $+$ denotes the group operation, and $n\cdot g := \underbrace{g + \cdots + g}_n$.  Let $\{g_1,\dots,g_n\}$ denote any (finite) generating set of $G$.

Every element of $G$ can be expressed in the form $g = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i g_i$ for some coefficients $\alpha_i \in \Bbb Z$.  Equivalently, the map from $\Bbb Z^n$ to $G$ defined by $\phi: (\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n) \mapsto \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i g_i$ is an onto group homomorphism.  The kernel of this homomorphism corresponds to the relations that these generators satisfy: $(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ is in the kernel of the homomorphism iff $\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i g_i = 0$.

Because $G$ is a finite group, it can be finitely presented.  That is, there exist coefficients $p_{ij}$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$ and $1 \leq j \leq m$ such that
$$
G = \left \langle g_1,\dots,g_n : \sum_{i=1}^n p_{ij} g_i = 0 \text{ for } j = 1,\dots,m \right \rangle
$$
and we see that $\ker \phi = \langle (p_{1j}, \dots,p_{nj}) : 1 \leq j \leq m \rangle \subset \Bbb Z^n$.  Thus, by the first isomorphism theorem we have
$$
G \cong \Bbb Z^n / \langle (p_{1j}, \dots,p_{nj}) : 1 \leq j \leq m \rangle.
$$
We could put this another way: define $P:\Bbb Z^m \to \Bbb Z^n$ to be the "linear" map corresponding to the matrix whose entries are $p_{ij}$.  Then we have $G \cong \Bbb Z^n / \operatorname{im}(P)$.

To connect this to the other answer, we might say that $G$ fits into the short exact sequence
$$
0 \to \Bbb Z^m \overset{P}\to \Bbb Z^n \overset{\phi}\to G \to 0
$$

Now, by Proposition 2.11 there exist invertible maps $J: \Bbb Z^m \to \Bbb Z^m$ and $K: \Bbb Z^n \to \Bbb Z^n$ such that $D= KPJ$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix described (with entries in $\Bbb Z$).  Now, it suffices to observe that $\Bbb Z^m/\operatorname{im}(P)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z^m/\operatorname{im}(D)$.  One way to see this is to consider the corresponding sequence
$$
0 \to \Bbb Z^m \overset{K\circ P\circ J}\to \Bbb Z^n \overset{J^{-1} \circ \phi}\to G \to 0
$$